# How can I get variable from the file config.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

Welcome
I have a file config.yml

```
d_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../src/FacebookBundle/Facebook/FacebookInit.php
    app_id: 296925470418713
    secret: fb4d0a99bcf80e55f47077ffadcac921
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location, user_about_me, user_location]
```

Then I have this class, which retrieves data from the file config.yml

```
<?php

namespace D\FacebookBundle\Facebook;

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use D\FacebookBundle\Facebook\Facebook;
use D\FacebookBundle\Facebook\FacebookConfig;

class FacebookInit
{
    public $hAPI;
    public $userProfile;
    public $user;
    public $logoutUrl;
    public $loginUrl;
    public $config;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = Yaml::parse('/facebookx/app/config/config.yml');

        $this->hAPI = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $this->config['d_facebook']['app_id'],
            'secret' => $this->config['d_facebook']['secret']
            ));
        $this->setUserProfile();
    }
}
```

What better way to do this? How can I get variable from the file config.yml?
I ask for an example?

Comment: Are you using the S2 framework?  If so, look up how to use parameters (and perhaps services) in the manual.

Comment: yes, I use Symfony2. I read it, but I still don't know how to do it

Comment: I suggest you regenerate your secret code for your app after posting it publicly here :)

Answer (score 1):

In your config file you would have something like:

```
parameters:
    d_facebook:
        file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../src/FacebookBundle/Facebook/FacebookInit.php
        app_id: 296925470418713
        secret: fb4d0a99bcf80e55f47077ffadcac921
        cookie: true
        permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location, user_about_me, user_location]
```

From a S2 controller you can get an array of the parameters with:

```
$faceBookParameters = $this->container->getParameter('d_facebook');
```

However you probably want to make your Facebook class a service and use dependency injection to set the parameters.  So in your services.yml:

```
services:        
    facebook:
        class:  Path\To\Facebook
        arguments:  
            - '%d_facebook%'  # This injects your parameters
```

The in your controller you would just do:

```
$facebook = $this->get('facebook');
```

Read through the section on services again.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do something like [expose a semantic configuration for a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)?

This is if you want to get the configuration from a root level configuration 'namespace' (like 'd_facebook').  You would create a Configuration and an Extension class in your bundle's DependencyInjection folder.  The configuration class would have a 'getConfigTreeBuilder' method that would define settings for the keys that can be in your namespace.  Then the extension class would have a 'load' method that would receive the parsed configuration and be able to use $container->setParameter('key', 'value') to allow access of the configuration in other classes.  The linked cookbook has further details.